# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

Can someone help me with this error? I have the updated version of Support Library.
I have tried invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: Please don't post text as image. The information should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `classpath 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'` from build.gradle(Project:VoiceRecorder) and add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'` to build.gradle(Module:app)

Answer (score 0):

update to this version and try

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

it may solve your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 http://i.imgur.com/cqPtiSg.png